# re-design this parallel pseudo code more DRY

Tags: ruby, parallel-processing

I have in mind a design problem that does not look like complex, but I can't find by myself a way to solve it. I would like to follow as much as possible the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

I have got two functions. One is the basic version of the algorithm, the other one is an improvement with parallel programming. They are two, and my aim is to write only one of them with an additional parameter, e.g., "parallel". Here the pseudo codes.

```
fun1 ()
    loop for par1 times
        do_work()

fun2 ()
    loop for par1 times
        run new thread
            do_work()
```

Currently I have coded

```
if parallel == 0
    fun1 ()
else
    fun2 ()
```

What I want is something like

```
fun ()
    loop for par1 times
        run new thread if parallel > 0 #Ruby's syntax-like
            do_work()
```

I was wondering if Ruby may help me solving this issue. I am a newbie of Ruby so I am not sure its functional programming could make the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like this:

```
def fun(parallel=false)
  if parallel
    # called as fun(true)
  else
    # called as fun
  end
end
```

`parallel=false` sets the default argument value if no argument is passed.

Or you could use an options hash to pass the parameters more explicitly

```
def fun(options={})
  parallel = option[:parallel] || false
  if parallel
    # called as fun(parallel: true)
  else
    # called as fun
  end
end
```

Another approach is to always run `do_work()` in a thread and to wait for the thread to finish depending on the `parallel` parameter.

```
def fun(parallel=false)
  workers = []
  par1.times do
    worker = Thread.new { do_work() }
    worker.join if parallel
    workers << worker
  end
  workers.each(&:join)
end
```

Comment: It perfectly works, but that is the same schema I want to change (second code box). My goal would be to call the function do_work() only once.

Comment: The key is to allow the spawn of at least one thread, that s true! Thanks!